# It's possible to set timer on poster node and other nodes in Roku..?

Tags: roku, brightscript, scenegraph

I am working on a Roku app using scene graph component.I am trying to set timer node on poster node in  Roku app playing on TV APP..i want to set timer on Poster Node And Other Nodes it is possible in Roku..? pls help me..

Comment: Timer Means. you tried to display the current time in your Application. otherwise, belove answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sure, it's possible.**

You can add *Timer* Node as child for *Poster* etc. It will looks in next way:

```
    <Poster
        id = "poster">
            <Timer
                id="timer"/>
    </Poster>
```

For more detailed answer, please describe you purpose.